# Android Widget with service (started using alarm) getting called frequently

Tags: android, android-widget, android-alarms, android-appwidget

In one requirement I have created one widget that should be updated after every 5 minutes. I found on internet that instead of using java thread I should use AlarmManager that will save the battery. Now I am doing it using AlarmManager.

The problem I am facing is the onStart method of Service class is getting called very very frequently. Almost 10 times in a second. Hear is my two classes.

```
public class MyAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
        intent = new Intent(context, UpdateWidgetService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

The Service class is

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {  

private Intent intent;

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
this.intent = intent;
System.out.println("This is getting printed 10 times in a second.");
final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplication(), 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
long interval = 3000;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending);     

stopSelf();
super.onStart(intent, startId);
 } 
}
```

I've also set property in xml file for auto refresh but it is no use. The app is not using the below property to refresh the widget. Also I wanted to know which method will be called if this property is used by the application.

```
android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the

```
super.onStart(intent, startId);
```

to the beginning of your method. It isn't right to call it after you've stopped the service with stopSelf();